No animation when switching between navigationStacks
I am working on an application in SwiftUI.
I use several coordinators and navigationStacks to navigate the app.
I try to switch current flow like this:
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    withAnimation {
        self.appCoordinator.changeFlow(to: CurrentFlow.random())
    }
}

But the animation does not work every time you change the current navigationStack.
For example, I have added a button for every screen to random switching between navigationStacks.
Due to the fact that there is a lot of code, I created a separate repository to provide an example of the code.
https://github.com/pashaPud/AnimationProblem/tree/main/ProblemWithAnimation

you can't use DispatchQueue in SwiftUI because the View data structs have no lifetime like objects do. You need to use .task or .task(id: someValue) if you want an async lifetime. Also you can't centralise state in a coordinator it needs to be distributed via @State / let / @Binding.
